# Print all characters in a string

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to print all characters in python, even ones which usually aren't printed?

For example

```
>>>print_all("skip
 line")
skip\nline
```

Comment: Do you mean printing out characters such as `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `'\s'`?

Comment: You can try to print its `repr` if that's what you're looking for: `print(repr("skip\nline"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even easier, cast it to a *raw string* by using `"%r"`, raw strings treat backslashes as literal characters:

```
print("%r" % """skip
line""")
skip\nline
```

Additionally, use `!r` in a `format` call:

```
print("{0!r}".format("""skip
line"""))
```

for similar results.

Comment: This works better for me, since I don't have to go through all the code changing my "print"s to "print()"s

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you want [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

```
>>> """skip
... line"""
'skip\nline'
>>>
>>> print(repr("""skip
... line"""))
'skip\nline'
>>> print(repr("skip    line"))
'skip\tline
```

So, your function could be

```
print_all = lambda s: print(repr(s))
```

And for Python 2, you need `from __future__ import print_function`